# Navigation in Blazor on .NET Core 3.0.0-preview5 between components

Tags: c#, navigation, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

Based on the book "Blazor Quick Start Guide", I tried implementing navigation between Razor pages. The book states that I need

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services;
```

and then I could use :

```
UriHelper.NavigateTo("mypage2");
```

but it seems that's been deprecated/removed - how would I do this in the current version of Blazor? I can't seem to find any useful blog post or tutorial that explains this in more detail.

Comment: It is clearly stated in the docs, [uri-and-navigation-state-helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers), so that you didn't find that searching for `UriHelper.NavigateTo` is odd.

Comment: Btw, why do you use preview 5 and not 6?

Comment: @LGSon: I shied away from preview-6 because of a long list of problems they have with EF Core in preview-6

Comment: As you _"dipping my toes into Blazor"_ you might want to do that with the latest preview (and care less with the rest). Also, a ["Release Candidate" is scheduled](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md) for July, which should mean any day soon.

Comment: @LGSon: good to hear about the pending RC release !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That interface was indeed moved, there was some problem with it being `static`.
It now is (with preview 6 at least)

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IUriHelper uriHelper
```